# Bison/Flex print value of terminal from alternative

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I have written a simple grammar:

```
operations :
    /* empty */
    | operations operation ';'
    | operations operation_id ';'
    ;

operation :
    NUM operator NUM
    {
        printf("%d\n%d\n",$1, $3);
    }
    ;

operation_id :
    WORD operator WORD
    {
        printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n",$1, $3, $<string>2);
    }
    ;

operator :
    '+' | '-' | '*' | '/'
    {
        $<string>$ = strdup(yytext);
    }
    ;
```

As you can see, I have defined an `operator` that recognizes one of 4 symbols. Now, I want to print this symbol in `operation_id`. Problem is, that logic in `operator` works only for last symbol in alternative.
So if I write **a/b;** it prints **ab/** and that's cool. But for other operations, eg. **a+b;** it prints **aba**. What am I doing wrong?

*I ommited new lines symbols in example output.

Answer (score 5):

This non-terminal from your grammar is just plain wrong.

```
operator :
    '+' | '-' | '*' | '/' { $<string>$ = strdup(yytext); }
    ;
```

First, in yacc/bison, each production has an action. That rule has four productions, of which only the last has an associated action. It would be clearer to write it like this:

```
operator : '+' 
         | '-'
         | '*'
         | '/' { $<string>$ = strdup(yytext); }
         ;
```

which makes it a bit more obvious that the action only applies to the reduction from the token `'/'`.

The action itself is incorrect as well. `yytext` should never be used outside of a *lexer* action, because its value isn't reliable; it will be the value at the time the most recent lexer action was taken, but since the parser usually (but not always) reads one token ahead, it will usually (but not always) be the string associated with the *next* token. That's why the usual advice is to make a copy of `yytext`, but the idea is to copy it *in the lexer rule*, assigning the copy to the appropriate member of `yylval` so that the parser can use the semantic value of the token.

You should avoid the use of `$<type>$ =`. A non-terminal can only have one type, and it should be declared in the prologue to the bison file:

```
 %type <string> operator
```

Finally, you will find that it is very rarely useful to have a non-terminal which recognizes different operators, because the different operators are syntactically different. In a more complete expression grammar, you'd need to distinguish between `a + b * c`, which is the sum of a and the product of b and c, and `a * b + c`, which is the sum of c and the product of a and b. That can be done by using different non-terminals for the sum and product syntaxes, or by using different productions for an expression non-terminal and disambiguating with precedence rules, but in both cases you will not be able to use an `operator` non-terminal which produces `+` and `*` indiscriminately.

For what its worth, here is the explanation of why `a+b` results in the output of `aba`:

1. The production `operator : '+'` has no explicit action, so it ends up using the default action, which is `$$ = $1`.
2. However, the lexer rule which returns `'+'` (presumably -- I'm guessing here) never sets `yylval`. So `yylval` still has the value it was last assigned.
3. Presumably (another guess), the lexer rule which produces `WORD` correctly sets `yylval.string = strdup(yytext);`. So the semantic value of the `'+'` token is the semantic value of the previous `WORD` token, which is to say a pointer to the string `"a"`.
4. So when the rule

   ```
   operation_id :
       WORD operator WORD
       {
           printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n",$1, $3, $<string>2);
       }
       ;
   ```

executes, `$1` and `$2` both have the value `"a"` (two pointers to the same string), and `$3` has the value `"b"`.

Clearly, it is semantically incorrect for `$2` to have the value `"a"`, but there is another error waiting to occur. As written, your parser leaks memory because you never `free()` any of the strings created by `strdup`. That's not very satisfactory, and at some point you will want to fix the actions so that semantic values are freed when they are no longer required. At that point, you will discover that having two semantic values pointing at the same block of allocated memory makes it highly likely that `free()` will be called twice on the same memory block, which is Undefined Behaviour (and likely to produce very difficult-to-diagnose bugs).